# Deserializing complex JSON object with GSON and RETROFIT

Tags: java, android, retrofit, gson

Learning android native and stuck on GSON Deserialize...
cant parse deep nested JSON object response from an API

The Data returning:

```
{
  "parent_type": "some_type",
  "data": {
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "some_id",
        "data": {
          "name": "some_name",
          "desc": "bla bla bla"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "some_other_id",
        "data": {
          "name": "some_other_name",
          "desc": "other bla bla bla"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a RETROFIT client looking like this:

```
    baseUrl = "https://www.someurl.com/";

    OkHttpClient client = createClientWithInterceptors();

    // create GSON deserializer
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Some.class, new SomeDeserializer());
    Gson myGson = gsonBuilder.create();

    _retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(myGson))
            .build();
```

The GET looks like this:

```
// end points
public interface Somethings {
    @GET("someendpoint/somthings?limit=2")
    Call<List<Something>> getSomething();
}
```

Then the deserializer looks like this:

```
    public class SubRedditDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Something>> {
        @Override
        public List<Something> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        // cant figure out how to handle this here..

        return something;
        }
     }
```

Also cant figure out what `Something` class structure should look.. should it be one `something` or an array?

At the end I want it to be a `List<Something>` when `Something` is:

```
public class Something {
    public String name;
    public String desc;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Read retrofit tutorials [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client).
for a deserializing json first copy your data returning string into pojo onile tools like jsonutils.com and get your correct model, retrofit can deserialize return data into your model automaticly.

Comment: The tutorial in link covers all the basics of Retrofit along with nested JSON Parsing. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Comment: KeLiuyue I did see comment on answer

Answer (score 1):

- your `JSON` is `JSONObject` ,so `List<Something>` is wrong .
- your Bean is `Something` ,it was part of return `JSON` value .So you can change to `ResponseBean`

Try to use this bean

**ResponseBean**

```
public class ResponseBean {

/**
 * parent_type : some_type
 * data : {"children":[{"id":"some_id","data":{"name":"some_name","desc":"bla bla bla"}},{"id":"some_other_id","data":{"name":"some_other_name","desc":"other bla bla bla"}}]}
 */

private String parent_type;
private DataBeanX data;

public String getParent_type() {
    return parent_type;
}

public void setParent_type(String parent_type) {
    this.parent_type = parent_type;
}

public DataBeanX getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(DataBeanX data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public static class DataBeanX {
    private List<ChildrenBean> children;

    public List<ChildrenBean> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<ChildrenBean> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public static class ChildrenBean {
        /**
         * id : some_id
         * data : {"name":"some_name","desc":"bla bla bla"}
         */

        private String id;
        private DataBean data;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public DataBean getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(DataBean data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public static class DataBean {
            /**
             * name : some_name
             * desc : bla bla bla
             */

            private String name;
            private String desc;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getDesc() {
                return desc;
            }

            public void setDesc(String desc) {
                this.desc = desc;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then

```
@GET("someendpoint/somthings?limit=2")
Call<ResponseBean> getSomething();
```

And use in this

```
@Override
public ResponseBean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    // cant figure out how to handle this here..

    return something;
}
```

**Edit**

```
[
    {
        "name": 12345,
        "desc": "3"
    },
    {
        "name": 12346,
        "desc": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": 12347,
        "desc": "1"
    }
]
```

If your `JSON` like code above ,you can use `List<Something>` in your code .

Comment: from my understanding, in this answer im parsing the result to the same structure when what I what is to get a list of only the `data` from each `children`. how can I achieve this?

Comment: KeLiuyue can you give an example of how I would use it after getting the `ResponseBean` object? Also I noticed that the deserializer is not even used this way right?

Comment: KeLiuyue - its working but again, Im ending up with the same structure as the response what I want to get at the end is the structure in your edit. What am I missing?

Comment: so eventually there is no way evading getting the array of `children` in the deserializer, looping through each one of them and casting to the new `Something` instance, adding to a `List` and returning it. Pretty ugly but works

Answer (score 0):

use addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()), Response returns full json as String. Convert String into JsonObject then parse it into your model.